# Mergin Maps Input map tips

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

**Background:**

Using QGIS 3.28.1, I have created a Mergin Maps project.  According to the Mergin documentation (https://merginmaps.com/docs/gis/features/#forms) map tips can be created (in Layer Properties > Display) that can contain up to three field values.  Here's a screen shot from that documentation that examples two field values:

[image]

However, when I add two or three fields, only the *last* field's value is displayed in the Mergin map tip.  For example if I were to list the fields *latitude* and *longitude* as shown below, only *longitude* displays in the Mergin app.

```
# fields
latitude
longitude
```

**Question:**

How to include two or three field values as map tips in the Mergin Input app?

**Edit:**

As requested, here are two screenshots.  The first shows the QGIS *Layer Properties > Display* tab with 3 fields intended for display in the app.  The second shows the resulting Mergin Input app screen.  Note that only the last field, *longitude*, is displayed.  This problem is not specific to the *longitude* field; the problem still occurs if other fields are listed last.

[image]

[image]

**Edit #2:**

If I leave the QGIS *Layer Properties > Display* tab blank, then 3 fields are displayed, but they are the first three fields in the database:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could take a screenshot of what you see and what you expect to see.

Comment: Good idea!  Please see my edits.

Comment: Ahh I see what you me a now. So personally I've never tried to mess with it too much when I did. I was never able to shake FID off the top, then the following two were either in alphabetical order or ordered by which field was the first in the list of the table. Really can't remember which. Sorry I'm not able to assist much on this one. Will follow though would be good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `HTML` in the "HTML map tip", it should work as expected:

```html
<h2>Installation: <font color="#0000FF">[% "installation_date" %]</font><br>
Longitude: <font color="#0000FF">[% "longitude" %]</font><br>
Latitude: <font color="#0000FF">[% "latitude" %]</font>
</h2>
```

And, best of all, you can show more than 3 rows.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!  May I ask where you found this info?  I looked all over, but alas, no joy...

Comment: @StuSmith - just tried it out. The name "HTML map tip" is an indication that HTML syntax is allowed.

Comment: I've asked a follow-up Mergin HTML question, hoping you might be able to help!