# How to word-wrap HTML in Mergin Input?

Tags: qgis, html, mergin-maps

This is a follow-up to a [question that I previously asked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447114/mergin-maps-input-map-tips) regarding QGIS map tips in Mergin.

Based on that answer, I am trying to display a text field **(location_description)** in the Mergin *input preview panel*, using HTML.  Here's the HTML that I enter into the QGIS Layer Properties > Display > HTML Map Tip:

```
<h2>
[% "location_description" %]
</h2>
```

And here's the Mergin display, which does not wordwrap.  How can I get the contents of this text field to wordwrap?

**Edit:** The [Mergin documentation](https://merginmaps.com/docs/gis/features/#settings-for-mergin-maps-input-preview-panel) for this topic does not mention word wrapping, leaving me to assume that it *should* happen by default.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to create a line break in HTML, like `style='word-break:break-all'` or using `<textarea>...</textarea>`, but unfortunately none of them work here.

Instead you can use the QGIS expression function `wordwrap`:

```
[%  wordwrap(  "location_description" ,30) %]
```

[image]

Comment: The wordwrap function looked promising.  However, it made no difference; Mergin still did not wordwrap.  I tried the various wordwrap options and settings, all to no effect.  Out of curiosity I also tested wordwrap to see if it made any difference with the QGIS tool tip.  It did not.  All of this got me wondering if there's a bug with wordwrap...?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with synchronization. Try to change something in your projekt (i.e. add a feature), save the project and synchronize again. BTW i'm using QGIS 3.28.1.

Comment: No, it's a problem with synchronization and with the '<h2>' tag. Try to use 'wordwrap' without '<h2>'.

Comment: Sometimes changing the project on the mobile device helps to refresh the display.

Comment: Removing the <h2> tag was the solution.  I am very happy!